# How to configure NLog conditions filter to recognize JSON quotes

Tags: c#, nlog

I'm trying to implement NLog condition filter by specific json attribute in a message.I saw question about single quote but it doesn't seem that same solution applies here (at least I can't get it to work)

`<when condition="contains('${message}', '"projectName":"Amber"')" action="LogFinal"></when>`
in my json I have

```
{"projectName":"Amber"}
```

Any suggestion how to properly rewrite a condition to estape `"`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to navigate through the Standard-XML-parser, so it has to be valid XML without quotes `"` inside the xml-attribute-values.

Maybe something like this:

```
<when condition="contains(message,'&quot;projectName&quot;:&quot;Amber&quot;')" action="LogFinal" />
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/When-Filter